# Changing Vertical Spacing After Heading (w. \linespread)

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, afterheading

For my paper, I need to use \linespread for linespacing. But I have such problem:

After seciton heading the vertical space is changing with respect to the size of the text after heading. Here I have 2 codes with different vertical size after heading:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\linespread{1.4} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \section{HEADER}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

And here with bigger size of text

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\linespread{1.4} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \section{HEADER}
  \lipsum[1-22]
\end{document}
```

without \linespread the vertical space is constant but with \linespread it changes based on the size of text. Is there any code to stabilize it ?

Note: I tried \setspace  and \onehalfspacing instaed of \linespread . It effects similarly.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It may not be obvious at first glance that this is a duplicate. However, if you know that option `twoside` also activates `\flushbottom`, it should become clear. At least the answers will then be relevant.

Comment: Additionally: See option `heightrounded` in the [`geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg) manual. (But in your case, this option is not enough to solve the problem, and therefore another solution, e.g., from the dup is still needed).

Comment: @cabohah thansk for pointing out. It helped!